# What is the logic of creating the Mysql SELECT Statement for drop down in Struts + JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, struts2

can you please help me rectify the code below, I'm trying to create a populated drop down list in struts 2 in Eclipse as my IDE. This is my first time to use 'STRUTS' as well as 'IDE ECLIPSE'. 
    To be specific by the SELECT statement I do not know how to write the code that, when a user selects the 'Make' of the car, the database extracts the different 'Models' of that make. But other select items like 'Color', should be optional in that a user can proceed to search for the 'Make' minus choosing an option from them.
    Please help I'm new in ActionClass and DataBase. Thanx in advance.

```
package drive;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CarSearch extends ActionSupport {

private String model;
private String modification;
private String engine;
private String color;
private String bodyType;
private String minPrice;
private String maxPrice;
private String mileage;
private int minYear;
private int maxYear;
private String make;

public String execute () {
    String ret = NONE;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Cars";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "$jademedia247");
        String sql = "SELECT make FROM type WHERE";
        sql+=" model = ? AND modification = ? ";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
        ps.setString(1, model);
        ps.setString(2, modification);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            make = rs.getString(1);
            ret = SUCCESS;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret = ERROR;
    } finally { 
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public String getModification() {
    return modification;
}

public void setModification (String modification) { 
    this.modification = modification;
}

public String getEngine() {
    return engine;
}

public void setEngine (String engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor (String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public String getBodyType() {
    return bodyType;
}

public void setBodyType(String bodyType) {
    this.bodyType = bodyType;
}

public String getMinPrice() {
    return minPrice;
}

public void setMinPrice(String minPrice) {
    this.minPrice = minPrice;
}

public String getMaxPrice () {
    return maxPrice;
}

public void setMaxPrice (String maxPrice) {
    this.maxPrice = maxPrice;

}


public String getMileage () {
    return mileage;
}

public void setMileage (String mileage) {
    this.mileage = mileage ;
}

public int getMinYear() {
    return minYear;
}
public void setMinYear(int minYear) {
    this.minYear = minYear;
}

public int getMaxYear() {
    return maxYear;
}
public void setMaxYear(int maxYear) {
    this.maxYear = maxYear;
}

public String getMake() {
return make;
}
public void setMake(String make){
    this.make = make;
}
}
```

Comment: to get more clarification regarding the struts and how to use to populate dropdown list go http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

Comment: @ Sumn2u, thanx for the ref. my issue particularly is using mysql database (SELECT statement in ActionClass) rather than ArrayList. More to that in my MySQL I would like to know the right syntax for SELECT statement for the search result.

Answer (score 2):

```
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT field_name FROM table_name WHERE model = ? AND modification = ? ");
    ps.setString(1, model);
    ps.setString(2, modification);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

//it will help you